# Failed to compile create-react-app due to lint warnings after ejecting

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint, create-react-app

I've been following a React course. The next step has been using `npm run eject` so that css modules can be used.

Since ejecting I can't use npm start. The page fails to compile. A long list of linting warnings appear (which actually appear to be from the webpack config files).

I have created a .eslintignore file for these and other files:

```
./reactNotes.jsx
./nodeTest.js
./config
./scripts
```

But neither my code editor (vs code) or webpack seems to notice this file. eslint is installed globally.

I have also investigated the webpack config for eslint with options like exclude:

```
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
    enforce: 'pre',
    use: [
      {
        options: {
          formatter: eslintFormatter,
          eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
        },
        loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
      },
    ],
    include: paths.appSrc,
    exclude: /config/
  }
```

VS Code has eslint enabled in my user settings.

How can I set up webpack (and maybe even vs code) to ignore directories and files?

update: here is .eslintrc:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "react-app",
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "jsx-a11y",
        "import"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "windows"
        ],
        "indent": [
            "error",
            4
        ],
        "react/prop-types": 0,
        "react/jsx-indent": 0,
        "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": 0,
        "jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions": 0,
        "max-len": 0,
        "arrow-body-style": 0,
        "react/jsx-indent-props": 0,
        "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,
        "react/jsx-no-bind": 0,
        "arrow-parens": 0,
        "react/no-array-index-key": 0
    }
}
```

Also npm install and restarting the browser do not work.

[image: browser errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loveky's answer fixes up VS code.

To fix the build add in an an exclude property to webpack.config that includes the service worker file:

```
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
    enforce: 'pre',
    use: [
      {
        options: {
          formatter: eslintFormatter,
          eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
          emitError: false,
        },
        loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
      },
    ],
    include: paths.appSrc,
    exclude: /(config|node_modules|registerServiceWorker.js|nodeTest.js|reactNotes.jsx|webpack.config)/,
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

in your eslintigonre, try change

```
./config
./scripts
```

to

```
config/
scripts/
```

In ESLint's doc, it stats:

> Ignore patterns behave according to the .gitignore specification

You can find the full specification [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)

Answer (score 2):

Create-react-app uses eslint internally for linting and doesn't run when that eslint check throws an error, if you have configured eslint separately(using config .eslintrc.js) and have then ejected, it starts using that eslint config that you have configued. The problem that i was facing is that, while using debugger, it wont start and throws an exception of `no-debugger` rule. So, i created a separate eslint config, and named it `test.eslintrc.js`, and in my `package.json` i did:

`"lint": "eslint src -c test.eslintrc.js",`

inside `"scripts"` tag

Also you can use .eslintignore and add directories: 
config/
scripts/
src/serviceWorker.js

Comment: Also, instead of having a separate test.eslintrc.js file, you can just modify `eslintConfig` available inside `package.json` and add your rules there.